# 301 redirect for all get request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all incoming requests get. for example: `site.com?anystr` to `site.com`

I tried to do so

```
RedirectMatch /?(.*)$ site.com
```

But it causes cyclic forwarding and i get browser error

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch). RedirectMatch will not match the query string. You are redirecting any request to `http://site.coom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is hat you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]
```

i.e. any URL with query string is redirected to root with query string stripped off using `?` in the target.

Comment: if i need redirect `sitecom/news.html/?sasfs` to `site.com/news.html` that I should finish? i tried this: `RewriteRule ^/news.html$ /news.html/? [L,R=302]` but it`s not works

Comment: That would be: `RewriteRule ^(news\.html)$ /$1? [L,R=302]` with the same `RewriteCond` as above.

Comment: it works when I add one thing. when i tried this: `RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /$1? [L,R=302]` AND `RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]` worked only one

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]` is catch-all which means it redirects everything. You cannot use both. Also please avoid adding questions from comments.

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectMatch` does match anything behind the domain name and before the query string. The regex `/?(.*)$` will match any request.

You will need to use mod_rewrite. Enable mod_rewrite in the main config file of Apache and restart Apache. Then add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [QSD,R,L]
```

Change the `[R]` flag to `[R=301]` after testing this works as expected.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^\? / [QSD,L,R=301]
`

Comment: What is your Apache version?